# XCode header search paths

Tags: ios, xcode, zxing

I am trying to use a third-party library in my ios project called ZXingObjC. I've added the library to my project by dragging the library's .xcodeproj file into my project. When I try to build, I get this error:

```
Lexical or Preprocessor Issue
 'ZXingObjC/ZXAztecDecoder.h' file not found
```

This is the offending line of code:

```
#import <ZXingObjC/ZXAztecDecoder.h>
```

The actual path (on my Mac's filesystem) to the .h file is:

```
/Users/jalmberg/Documents/ios/projects/ZXingObjC/ZXingObjC/aztec/decoder/ZXAztecDecoder.h
```

I've added the path to the Header Search Path, using the following:

```
/Users/jalmberg/Documents/ios/projects/ZXingObjC         recursive
```

I've tried several variations on this search path, but nothing works.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem looks like your path. If you are using this:

```
/Users/jalmberg/Documents/ios/projects/ZXingObjC         recursive
```

and the path is:

```
/Users/jalmberg/Documents/ios/projects/ZXingObjC/ZXingObjC/aztec/decoder/ZXAztecDecoder.h
```

Then you would could just use

```
#import <ZXAztecDecoder.h>
```

Note that it searches based on the relative path you defined in your import. So

```
#import <ZXingObjC/ZXAztecDecoder.h>
```

Is looking for a path that has the directory ZXingObjC which contains the file ZXAztecDecoder.h.

Comment: That did it. That #import line was in the library, so I assumed it was right, but when I removed the ZXingObjC/ from the import, it all worked. Thank you for the quick reply.

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer per-say but have you looked at cocoa pods, makes working with 3rd party libs sooo much easier, made me like developing ios again.

Dead simple to setup

http://cocoapods.org/